# Show that the Intersection of ε-neighbourhoods of a closed set E is equal to E

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm taking a real analysis course and we have only covered the basics of topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We are given a non-empty closed subset E of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define
$$
E_{\epsilon} = \bigcup\limits_{x\in E}\mathbb{B}(x, \epsilon)
$$

The question is the prove that
$$
\bigcap\limits_{\epsilon \gt 0}E_{\epsilon} = E
$$

I've tried showing that they are subsets of each other but I clearly don't understand the underlying objects well enough to form a coherent argument. Any hints or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion $E\subseteq \bigcap_{\epsilon>0} E_\epsilon$ should be obvious by definition. On the other hand, let $x\in \bigcap_{\epsilon>0} E_\epsilon$. If we can express $x$ as the limit of some sequence of elements of $E$ then we are done since $E$ is closed. Let's build this sequence inductively:

- Since $x\in E_1$, we can find some $x_1 \in E$ such that $\|x-x_1\|_2<1$
- Since $x\in E_{1/2}$, we can find some $x_2 \in E$ such that $\|x-x_2\|_2<1/2$

Continuing this way, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we can find some $x_n\in E$ such that $\|x-x_n\|_2\leq 1/n$. This implies that $x_n \to x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and since every $x_n \in E$ it must be the case that $x\in E$.

Notice that there isn't anything special about $1/n$, we could have chosen any sequence $a_n$ that goes to $0$.